# Unable to start the Docker daemon if file /etc/docker/daemon.json exist

Tags: docker

Wheh the /etc/docker/daemon.json exists, docker no longer started!

I installed docker from snap, so service docker restart will not work.
I start docker with

```
sudo snap start docker
```

The output from journalctl -xe is:

```
Aug  20 09:08:44 user-TV kernel: aufs aufs_fill_super:912:mount[1404]: no arg
Aug  20 09:08:44 user-TV kernel: overlayfs: missing 'lowerdir'
Aug  20 08:55:29 user-TV audit[644]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.docker.dockerd" name="/etc/docker/daemon.json" pid=644 comm="dockerd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=1000
Aug  20 08:55:29 user-TV docker.dockerd[644]: unable to configure the Docker daemon with file /etc/docker/daemon.json: open /etc/docker/daemon.json: permission denied
Aug  20 08:55:29 user-TV kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1534726529.513:7216): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.docker.dockerd" name="/etc/docker/daemon.json" pid=644 comm="dockerd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=1000
Aug  20 08:55:29 user-TV systemd[1]: snap.docker.dockerd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

Why it failed with open /etc/docker/daemon.json: permission denied in line 4 even I chmod 777 to it?

The content of the file is:

```
{
    "experimental": true
}
```

The docker version is 17.06.2-ce

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an AppArmor policy which is blocking access to this file.

> Aug  20 08:55:29 user-TV audit[644]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.docker.dockerd" name="/etc/docker/daemon.json" pid=644 comm="dockerd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=1000

Modify the apparmor to allow this and you should be ok

Comment: Yes! I forgot all sanppy apps have this problem!

Answer (score 0):

I configure Docker to listen to both a Unix socket (default) and to an all-interfaces TCP port. After updating to `Docker version 18.09.0, build 4d60db4` I could no longer start Docker while using `/etc/docker/daemon.json` on `Centos 7.5`.

`journalctl -xe` reported:

```
Nov 12 08:58:45 my.dev dockerd[6778]: unable to configure the Docker daemon with file /etc/docker/daemon.json: the following directives are specified both as a flag and in the configuration file: hosts: (from flag: [unix://],
```

On systemd systems the daemon.json config option is [no longer supported](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd//#daemon-configuration-file). Instead:

1. sudo rm /etc/daemon/daemon.json
2. sudo systemctl edit docker.service

   `[Service]
   ExecStart=
   ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock -H tcp://0.0.0.0:1234`
3. sudo systemctl daemon-reload
4. sudo systemctl restart docker.service